# How to solve $a^2 = b^2$

Tags: roots, absolute-value

It looks pretty simplistic but for me it's a bit complicated >.<.

So this is line one: $a^2 = b^2$

Next we square root both of them. $\sqrt {a^2} = \sqrt {b^2}$

Next move is the part that I'm not sure of.
Is it this? $|a| = |b|$
If yes then this?! $\pm a = \pm b$

Please help me.

Comment: That can be simplified to $a = b$ or $a = -b$. It's correct.  The important thing that you successfully remembered was $ \sqrt {a^2} = |a|$ (same wrt b).  Another option is proceeding as Dr.Sonnhard has, below.

Comment: Looks fine. However, it is simpler to consider only one pair of signs:$$a=\pm b$$which should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

note that $$a^2 = b^2 \iff a^2-b^2=0\iff (a+b)(a-b) = 0$$

Comment: I was going to write this as a second option but I forgot :P

Comment: Again, if ever I make an edit to a post of yours, I'm only doing so to help your answer succeed.) You are free of course, to roll back the edit, or edit the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ for any real number $x$.

Thus, the equation is equivalent to $|a|=|b|$ and there are two solutions: $a=b$ or $a=-b$.

Comment: $a^2 - b^2 = 0$ and $2ab = 1$ Depending on which I solve first I get more solutions if I choose to solve $a^2 - b^2 = 0$ and then substitute the solution into the other equation.

Comment: @alienCY Why do you think $2ab = 1$? Check your algebra.

Comment: Trying to solve $\sqrt i$

I think the answer lies on the fact that $a \in R$. I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z49hXoN4KWg&t=302s